# Count up if value changes in other dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

My input is:

```
d = {'x': [1479903, 1479879, 1479926, 1479736, 1479760, 1479784, 1479808, 1479831, 1480331, 1480355, 1480949, 1480973, 1480997, 1481021, 1481877, 1481901, 1481924, 1481948, 1481996, 1482020], 'y': [7195293, 7195293, 7195293, 7194829, 7194829, 7194829, 7194829, 7194829, 7194829, 7194829, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7194384, 7193920, 7193920], 'group':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.sort_values(by = ['group', 'y','x'], ascending = [True, False, True])
```

The dataframe is already sorted. The desired output is to create a column called 'subgroup' that starts at 1 and then only counts up when the y-value changes and starts over at 1 when the group number changes. Also create another column called 'count' that counts up until the 'subgroup' changes, when 'subgroup' changes then the 'count' starts over at 1. The desired output should look like:

| group | subgroup | count | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1479879 | 7195293 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1479903 | 7195293 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1479926 | 7195293 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1479736 | 7194829 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1479760 | 7194829 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1479784 | 7194829 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 1479808 | 7194829 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 1479831 | 7194829 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1480331 | 7194829 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1480355 | 7194829 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1480949 | 7194384 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1480973 | 7194384 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 1480997 | 7194384 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 1481021 | 7194384 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1481877 | 7194384 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1481901 | 7194384 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1481924 | 7194384 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1481948 | 7194384 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1481996 | 7193920 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1482020 | 7193920 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The dataframe is already sorted". Are you sure?

Comment: It is sorted first by 'group' ascending order, then by 'y' descending order, then by 'x' ascending order. df = df.sort_values(by = ['group', 'y','x'], ascending = [True, False, True])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['subgroup new'] = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: (x['y'] != x['y'].shift()).cumsum()).values
df['count new'] = df.groupby(['group', 'subgroup new']).cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    group  subgroup  count        x        y  subgroup new  count new
0       1         1      1  1479879  7195293             1          1
1       1         1      2  1479903  7195293             1          2
2       1         1      3  1479926  7195293             1          3
3       1         2      1  1479736  7194829             2          1
4       1         2      2  1479760  7194829             2          2
5       1         2      3  1479784  7194829             2          3
6       1         2      4  1479808  7194829             2          4
7       1         2      5  1479831  7194829             2          5
8       2         1      1  1480331  7194829             1          1
9       2         1      2  1480355  7194829             1          2
10      2         2      1  1480949  7194384             2          1
11      2         2      2  1480973  7194384             2          2
12      2         2      3  1480997  7194384             2          3
13      2         2      4  1481021  7194384             2          4
14      3         1      1  1481877  7194384             1          1
15      3         1      2  1481901  7194384             1          2
16      3         1      3  1481924  7194384             1          3
17      3         1      4  1481948  7194384             1          4
18      3         2      1  1481996  7193920             2          1
19      3         2      2  1482020  7193920             2          2
```